# JSON from javascript in index.html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, angularjs

I have a resume structure that I am trying to build up using Json. The resume section is as follows:

```
Cisco
- Software Engineer
    - Try different technologies to make user friendly applications
    - Playing with javascript and Json to create a personal website
```

I have a JSON structure for it as follows:

```
{
"sections":
[
{
  "company": "Cisco",
  "title":"Software Engineer",
  "desc": 
        [
        {
          "line1": "Try different technologies to make user friendly applications",
          "line2": "Playing with javascript and Json to create a personal website"
        }
        ]
}
] 
}
```

I am using the follwing script in index.html to fetch the json data:

```
  <div ng:switch-when="job" itemscope itemprop="organization" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
            <section class="job {{isLast(section.data.length,$index)}}"  ng:repeat="job in section.data">
             <h2>{{job.company|microdata:"name"}}{{job.url|external}}</h2>
             <h3>{{job.title}}</h3>
             <h2>{{job.desc.line1}}</h2>
             <h2>{{job.desc.line2}}</h2>
             </section>
</div>
```

I am not getting the line1 & line2 as expected output. Am I doing something wrong or it penetrates upto level 1 in key value pair?

I am a complete newbie in json and javascript, so please guide. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Desc` is an array, with an object in it. You would want to change the JSON, removing the `[]` brackets from `data`, and just make it an object (ie `{}`).

```
{
    "sections": [{
        "company": "Cisco",
        "title": "Software Engineer",
        "desc": {
            "line1": "Try different technologies to make user friendly applications",
            "line2": "Playing with javascript and Json to create a personal website"
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created your desc as an array, if you would like to use it without changing your HTML then change "desc" to:

```
"desc": {
          "line1": "Try different technologies to make user friendly applications",
          "line2": "Playing with javascript and Json to create a personal website"
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

In your data, desc is an array. I'd suggest a slight change in your data model (do it on your source or in a controller) to leverage the array values through the `ng-repeat` directive.

```
{
      "company": "Cisco",
      "title":"Software Engineer",
      "desc": [
         "Try different technologies to make user friendly applications",
          "Playing with javascript and Json to create a personal website"
      ]
}
```

See the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArnaudRinquin/3e8qJ/).

Comment: in this case he would have to change the HTML as well.

Comment: Sure, but that would be way cleaner (DRY: one line of template handles all potential lines). This data structure is far from being the right one.